# Integrate a UI in JavaScript into a UWP app

Tags: javascript, uwp

I am developing a UWP app and I have the UI part of the app developed in javascript. I am wondering if I can embed or integrate this UI javascript in the UWP application, or I need to rewrite the whole UI in UWP. Does anyone know?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There is logic of `Webview`.

In which you can define URL for your Application and it loads same in a App as if it was an App.

In windows soemthing like thsi

**In XAML**

```
<WebView .../>
```

**In class**

```
try
{
    Uri targetUri = new Uri(Address.Text);
    webView1.Navigate(targetUri);
}
catch (FormatException ex)
{
    // Bad address.
}
```

You ca see more detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview)

Answer (score 2):

UWP supports JavaScript directly. You don't have to choose either/or.

You can create a new project in Visual Studio from a JavaScript template and then copy in your existing HTML and JavaScript.

```
New Project -> JavaScript -> Blank App (Universal Windows)
```

See [Create a "Hello, world" app (JS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-hello-world-app-js-uwp) in the UWP docs on MSDN.

You can optionally add .Net or native code to your project by creating Windows Runtime Components and calling them from your JavaScript code.

If you prefer to have your HTML/JavaScript as an island inside an otherwise Xaml UI then you can do that by hosting the HTML/JavaScript in a WebView. You can then write the rest of the app in Xaml and your choice of .Net or C++.

Comment: Note that UWP JavaScript support is on the way out, it already was dropped from Visual Studio 2019 and documentation gets harder and harder to come by. You are definitely better of using the C#/C++ plus webview route.